# Recaptcha V2 Image challege coming behind the iframe

Tags: jquery, css, iframe, recaptcha

I have added reCaptchaV2 in an iframe, and the checkbox and everything is coming fine.

But sometime when the extra challenge comes with images to select, it is rendering behind my iframe.

as below

[image]

if I Can select the div in below image (one in light blue selection)and change it's z-index value.
it will come above my iframe.

[image]

but i am not able to select it.

I have tried the following

1. adding following css

```
.g-recaptcha-bubble-arrow + div
{
    position: absolute !important;
    z-index: 3000000000 !important;
}
```

But it is selecting the div below the g-recaptcha-bubble-arrow only and changing the z-index of it won't do.

2. Using this jQuery

```
$('.g-recaptcha-bubble-arrow').parent('div').css('z-index', 3000000000);
```

Nope. no change

3. Adding this css

```
iframe[title="recaptcha challenge"] {
    position: absolute !important;
    z-index: 3000000000 !important;
}
```

This also have no effect

How i can select the parent div of all (the one in above screenshot of recaptcha challenge css) ?

if i could get to select it and change it's z-index the following will be the output.
which is what i desire to attain.

[image]

Please Help me on this.

Comment: How are you implementing reCaptchaV2? Are you forcing it into an iframe for some particular reason?

Comment: ya the iframe is a form to fill and there is a submit button, the captcha should be in the form.

Comment: try `position: fixed;`

Comment: i tried position: fixed also, but no luck.
i'm looking for correct selector for that parent div

Comment: what is the form `position` / `z-index`? The form will need a `position` rule in order for it to understand `z-index`

Comment: wow i feel like a stupid now, i just set the z-index of my form to less than 2000000000(the default z-index of this challenge iframe). and i worked.
thanks @BenTheHumanMan for the comment, it made me think.

But it will be better to know the correct selector for that div though